# How to query in Apache Spark that has Dataset with JSONObject

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an entity class called "EntityModel.java" whose contents are like below :

```
public class EntityModel implements Serializable {

private String id;
private String user;
private JSONObject data;
..... (Getters and Setters)

}
```

> Sample JSONObject data : {"order":500, "comments":"comment1"}

Now, I am fetching the data like below :

```
List<EntityModel> dataLst = (List<EntityModel>) EntityModel.findAll();
```

Then,

```
Encoder<EntityModel> entityModelEncoder = Encoders.bean(EntityModel.class);
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .master(<<config>>)
            .appName(<<app Name>>).getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> dataSet = spark.createDataset(dataLst,entityModelEncoder).toDF();
```

Now, I want to use Spark sql like this mentioned below,

```
dataSet.createOrReplaceTempView("testview");
Dataset<Row> queryData = dataSet.sqlContext().sql("SELECT id,user,data.order FROM testview");
```

It gives exception and cannot read the data within the data object
"Cannot resolve 'testview.`data`['order']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires struct<> type, however, ''order'' is of string type."

What needs to be done here?

I have edited to a standalone class. Could you please check

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put("wastage",1.5);
        TestModel t1 = new TestModel();
        t1.setId("123");
        t1.setData(jsonObj);

        List<TestModel> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        lst.add(t1);

        Encoder<TestModel> StyleEncoder = Encoders.bean(TestModel.class);
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .master("local[2]")
                .appName("Test").getOrCreate();
        Dataset<Row> dataSet = spark.createDataset(lst,StyleEncoder).toDF();
        dataSet.show();
        dataSet.printSchema();
       // String tt = dataSet.schema().json();
        StructType details = new StructType(new StructField[]{
                new StructField("wastage", DataTypes.FloatType, true, Metadata.empty())
        });
     //   DataType dtType = DataType.fromJson(tt);
        Dataset<Row> dataSet1 = dataSet.withColumn("data",functions.from_json(functions.col("data"), details));

        dataSet1.show();

        dataSet.createOrReplaceTempView("testview");
        Dataset<Row> finalData = dataSet.sqlContext().sql("SELECT id,  data.wastage FROM testview ");
        finalData.show();
    }

}
```

And the model class as :

```
public class TestModel implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String id;


    private JSONObject data;


    public TestModel() {
    }

    public TestModel(String id, JSONObject data) {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public JSONObject getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(JSONObject data) {
        this.data = data;
    }



    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: can you show print schema of your dataframe ?

Comment: root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: struct
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)

Comment: Does that help or you need any other information

Comment: thanks , can you also show sample input for `private JSONObject data;` json

Comment: Its something like below
{"order":500, "comments":"comment1”,”color”:”blue”,”size”:30}

Comment: `data` is of type Map[Struct,Struct], can you print some sample data ?

Comment: can you add your pom.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

As per our discussion & You have mentioned schema in comments like below

```
root 
    |-- id: string (nullable = true) 
    |-- user: string (nullable = true) 
    |-- data: map (nullable = true) 
    |   |-- key: struct 
    |   |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Sample Data for `data` column is

```
{"order":500, "comments":"comment1","color":"blue","size":30}
```

To access `order` column from `data` column is of type `map`, we have to use for something like `data['order']`

Please use below code.

```
val schema = DataType.fromJson("""{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"color","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"comments","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"order","type":"long","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"size","type":"long","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}""").
asInstanceOf[StructType]

dataSet
.withColumn("data",from_json(col("data"),schema))
.createOrReplaceTempView("testview");

Dataset<Row> queryData = dataSet.sqlContext().sql("SELECT id,user,data.order as order FROM testview");
```

Comment: Srinivas, Thanks for the quick reply.
I am still getting the error as mentioned below.

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'testview.`data`['order']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires struct<> type, however, ''order'' is of string type.; line 1 pos 0;

Comment: in that case you gave me wrong schema .. can you please update print schema in your question ?

Comment: printSchema I have checked. It is the same that I have shared

Comment: This is the sample dataSet.show() output

+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+--------+---------------+
|id|           user|                data|                +------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+--------+---------------+
|  abc|xyz|{{} -> {}, {} -> ...|+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+--------+---------------+

Comment: Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: `data` column is not proper json & I just used `from_json` to extract json, try now & let me know if its not working.. i added scala code & may be you need to transform this code to java.

Comment: I have done like this and the error is :

`Dataset<Row> dataSet = spark.createDataset(dataLst,entityModelEncoder).toDF();
dataSet.show();
dataSet.printSchema();
 StructType details = new StructType(new StructField[]{
                new StructField("order", DataTypes.FloatType, true, Metadata.empty())
        });
        dataSet.withColumn("data",functions.from_json(dataSet.col("data"),details)).createOrReplaceTempView("testview");`

Comment: Exception is:
`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'from_json(`data`)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, '`data`' is of map<struct<>,struct<>> type.;`

Comment: @Srinavas 
For simplicity i have added testclass, please check the code in question above